# Samba setup to request password reset on first time login

Tags: samba, server-message-block, smb-conf

Is it possible to setup Samba to ask for password reset when the user first logs in without the need to setup a domain controller?
Would this work properly with Windows clients or with clients using Linux with file managers like Krusader or Nautilus?
Could somebody give me a few pointers how to implement this if is possible?
I'm pretty new to Samba and I use it as a file server and I would like to have such a feature on it, but I'm not sure if it's possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@crazybyte, @Nexus: Of course this is possible. See the explanation of *passwd chat* and *passwd program* parameters in `man smb.conf`.

(Sorry for mis-using an answer for what should be a comment to your answer. My karma doesn't increase here (as opposed to stackoverflow.com and superuser.com), so I'm not allowed to comment...)

Comment: Question was is it possible to reset the samba password from the *client* (Windows or Krusader/Nautilus). The commands you provided are for running on the Samba server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use preexec on the user-share and fire up a Infobox (net send like).
under linux you can use this one :
`echo "text" | smbclient -M hostname`
%m or %I can be used instead of hostname. (`man smb.conf` for the meaning)

There you can point out the need of pw-changing.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible. Samba is an implementation of the SMB/CIFS protocol, which doesn't contain password reset functionality.